# Printing WPF - no paging, adjust page size instead

Tags: wpf, printing

I have a till roll printer and I want to print on it. I don't need paging but I do need to adjust the page size instead. No matter what code I use the printer page size always uses the settings in the Printer Preferences.

```
        PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
        ps.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("rec", 200, 900);

        System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();

        MyPaginator paginator = new MyPaginator(print);
        paginator.PageSize = new Size(200, 900);
        printDialog.PrintDocument(paginator, "My Receipt");
```

I'm using a `DocumentPaginator` as I thought this would allow be to be more specific about the page I wanted to print.

How can I set the page size?

Comment: Is the printer set as the default printer? I had some issues with getting the paper size from a non default printer in Silverlight, the same *may* be the case here.

Comment: yes, by using the windows forms PrintDocument I can successfully print the desired length (9 inches) but I need to print a Usercontrol.